# cmp instruction not making jge jump within InsertionSort

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to write an iterative version of InsertionSort using MASM. After repeatedly getting unexpected errors, I tried running through the code line by line and watching in the debugger that it did what I expected. Sure enough, I the cmp instruction within my 'while loop' doesn't seem to be jumping every time it's supposed to:

```
; store tmp in edx
    movzx edx, word ptr[ebx + esi * 2];   edx: tmp = A[i]
    ...
    //blah blah

while_loop :
...
    movzx eax, word ptr[ebx + 2 * edi]
    cmp dx, ax
    jge exit_while
```

For example, if I use the data given, after the first 'for loop' iteration, I get to the point where EDX=0000ABAB, and EAX=00003333. I reach the lines:

```
cmp dx, ax
jge exit_while
```

Since ABAB>3333, I'd expect it to jump to exit_while, yet it doesn't!

What is going on here??? I'm at a total loss.

```
.data
arr word 3333h, 1111h, 0ABABh, 1999h, 25Abh, 8649h, 0DEh, 99h
sizeArr dword lengthof arr
printmsg byte "The array is: [ ", 0
comma byte ", ", 0
endmsg byte " ]", 0

.code
main proc
    call printArr
    call crlf
    push sizeArr
    push offset arr
    call insertionsort
    call crlf
    call printArr
    call crlf
    call exitprocess
main endp


insertionsort proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    _arr = 8
    len = _arr + 4

    mov ebx, [ebp + _arr]
    mov ecx, [ebp + len]
    dec ecx
    mov esi, 1; store i in esi, with i=1 initially

;   for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
forloop:

; store tmp in edx
    movzx edx, word ptr[ebx + esi * 2];   edx: tmp = A[i]

; store j in edi, where in initially j = i
    mov edi, esi
;set j=i-1
    dec edi

;while (j >= 0 &&   tmp<arr[j])
while_loop :
    cmp edi, 0
    jl exit_while
    movzx eax, word ptr[ebx + 2 * edi]
; cmp dx, [ebx + 2 * edi]
    cmp dx, ax
    jge exit_while

; A[j] = A[j-1]
    push word ptr [ebx+2*edi]
    pop word ptr [ebx+2*edi+2]
; j = j - 1
    dec edi
    jmp while_loop

exit_while:
    push dx
    pop word ptr[ebx + 2*edi+2]
    ; mov[ebx + edi], dx;    A[j] = tmp
    inc esi;     i = i + 1
    loop forloop

finished:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 8
insertionsort endp



printArr proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, offset sizeArr
    mov ecx, [ebx]
    mov esi, offset arr
    mov edx, offset printmsg
    call writestring
    mov edx, offset comma
loop1 :
    movzx eax, word ptr [esi]
    call writeHex
    call writestring
    add esi, 2
loop loop1

    mov edx, offset endmsg
    call writestring
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
printArr endp
```

Answer (score 4):

`jge` is the version for signed values - as such, a word with the value `ABAB` is negative - hence the comparison result you see.

Try `jae` (jump if above or equal) instead - the unsigned equivalent.

Comment: Thank you.... I can't believe that's what the problem was this whole time.

Comment: @AdamG: Since you zero-extended your 16-bit values into 32-bit registers anyway, instead of using `cmp ax, [ebx + 2 * edi]` or something, there's no point using a 16-bit operand-size override, just use `cmp eax, edx`.  (And then your signed compare would have worked for sort of the wrong reason.)  But using a 16-bit memory source operand is probably more efficient.  And BTW, yes `movzx` is usually the best choice for 16-bit loads, better than merging into the existing EAX with `mov ax, [addr]`